# Using different encodings at the same time

Tags: fonts, greek, font-encodings, characters

I need to write a letter which looks like the small greek epsilon but in large (like a capital). I found on page 17 of [this document](https://ftp.rrzn.uni-hannover.de/pub/mirror/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) the possibility of using \m{E} for it, which comes close enough. But that is only possible with the T4 encoding of fontec, but i want to use the T1. I tried using both encodings at the same time with

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontec}
\usepackage[T4]{fontec}
```

and this try with T4 first and also with `\usepackage[T1,T4]{fontec}` with T4 also first and than T1. But TexMaker uses always the last called encoding (T4 in this example) and gives me an error (\m not found in T1) with T1 as the last called argument.

**So is there any possibility of using this letter?** Or does someone have a different solution?

Thanks

Comment: please always post a complete small test file and show any error you got. the package is `fontenc` with an `n` and it is common to use multiple font encodings. Use T1 for English text and use `\fontencoding{T4}\selectfont` when you need T4

Comment: Yes, fontec is just a typo an i have ```fontenc```in my file. But i don´t understand how i should use your suggestion. Where do i put my \m{E}? It´s hard to make a good small test file as i want to insert just one letter with a different encoding in a text which is all T1.

Comment: I make enough typos to recognise a typo, but typos in code fragments (and incomplete fragments) mean code posted has not been tested, which is always a bad sign.

Comment: (it seems the "letters" tag is for letters-the-documents, not letters-the-characters)

Comment: @David Carlisle no it is really a typo ´cause in my head i alwas remember fon-tec easier than fon-tenc (or fon-TANK, which i use now as a memory hook).

Comment: @DanielDiniz no it is letter like capital letter or yes, like alphabetic character. I want to use one character which is onl possible with a different encoding format than the rest of the document.

Comment: @Phasco Daniel was commenting on your tagging the question [tag:letters] (I fixed the tags)

Comment: @Phasco it does not matter why the typo appears but (a) you could edit the question to fix it, and (b) you would have seen this before posting if you had posted a document rather than a code fragment. `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T4,T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
AB\m{E}C
\end{document}` for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want T4, for which only bitmap fonts are available. A similar glyph is in the Cyrillic encoding T2B.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2B,T1]{fontenc}

\DeclareTextSymbol{\Bigeps}{T2B}{"9B}
\DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\Bigeps}{T2B}

\begin{document}

E\Bigeps E

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also input the character directly: it is U+0510 CYRILLIC REVERSED ZE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2B,T1]{fontenc}

\DeclareTextSymbol{\Bigeps}{T2B}{"9B}
\DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\Bigeps}{T2B}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0510}{\Bigeps}

\begin{document}

E\Bigeps E

EԐE

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! that works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can access T4 just for that letter, although currently the T4 encoding is not available as scalable fonts:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T4,T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

AB{\fontencoding{T4}\selectfont\m{E}}C
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice! that works. Thanks!